# Intermediate certificates on NLB load balanced servers

Tags: ssl, iis-7

I am fairly sure I know how to install the 'main' certificate on load balanced servers (install on one,  export,  import to the others)  but I'm not quite sure what to do about the intermediate certificate (the one you install using the certificates snap in in mmc)  Do I manually install it using mmc on each server? or is there a similar process involved to the main cert (install, then export, then import on the others?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intermediate certificates are just certificates that chain your SSL certificate to the root certificates.  This is especially handy for older browsers.  The steps are essentially the same as installing SSL certificates.

Chances are, you bought your SSL certificate from the likes of GoDaddy, Verisign or others.  The process is simple if you're using IIS.

For example, [GoDaddy's instructions are over here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5346/installing-an-ssl-server-instructions?locale=en).  However, if your provider is not GoDaddy, I'm fairly certain the process is almost the same except on how your SSL certificate provider actually provides your certificate.

Comment: But godaddy doesn't explain how to copy the certificate to the other servers in your load balanced group.  You can't just install them on each server, you have to install on one and copy/export to the others.  I wasn't sure if the same applied to the intermediate certificate but apparently it does.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.  If this is a new LB set of IIS servers, then yeah, I would just install the intermediate certificate, no need to export / import.  However, if you're ADDING to your load balanced cluster, then I would see your course of action being the correct one but except, you would have to do it once and then just import it to the remaining servers.

Comment: When I get the intermediate certificate, do I go on to server A, mmc, import it to "Intermediate Certification Authorities" then do the same (with the original file) on server B?   **OR**... do I import it on A,  then export it on A, and import the exported version on B?

Comment: You can do the 2nd method provided you make sure to enable "include all certificates in certification path" when you perform your export.